# How to display halfwidth Unicode characters in gnome-terminal etc

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode, terminal-emulator

I'm wanting to set up vim with conceal to display the unicode characters U+2329 (`〈`) and U+232A (`〈`) in place of `<` and `>` when used to indicate type parameters. These are half-width characters that display just fine in Leafpad, Firefox, or indeed the preview area in the gnome-terminal font selector (all using BitStream Vera Sans). However when displaying these characters in the terminal, they actually take up two character cells. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Unicode standard, these are wide characters.

See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/tr11-28.html: 4 -> ED4 for the definition of "W", and 6.3 -> Data11 to check that these characters indeed belong to this category.